# Horário da timezone diferente do esperado

Tags: debate, suporte

Percebi que o StackOverflow em Português está operando com o horário UTC, acredito que deveria configurar para a zona horária do usuário, no meu caso `America/Sao_Paulo` (que atualmente está no horário de verão)

Veja o horário da questão é 22:43, mas aqui aparece com o "UTC +3", ou seja o Brasil no meu caso deveria ser -3, mas é exibido 1:43:

[image: utc]

Nesta outra image:

[image: horario servidor para países de língua portuguesa]

- O `+35` eu recebi as 22:33 no dia 24/12 (ao menos é o que parece)
- Este `+10` recebi as 23:20 no dia 24/12, porém está contabilizando como dia 25/12

Exibindo o código fonte da área do `+10` ele mostra dia 25:

`<td class="rep-day" data-load-url="..." title="2014-12-25">`

No código fonte do `+35` aparece dia 24/12:

`<td class="rep-day " data-load-url="..." title="2014-12-24">`

Suponho que cada país que acessa uma comunidade do StackExchange utiliza as configurações como preestabelecido (off: maldita reforma ortográfica, sempre me confundindo) na conta do usuário, ou pelo menos deveria fazer isto.

Acredito que seja algo na configuração da minha conta, porém tentei revirar tudo e não encontro aonde configuro a minha localização ou zona horária. Ou está configuração é feita por uma base de dados de IPs por região (semelhante ao http://www.maxmind.com)?

Comment: Relacionado: [Em qual timezone o StackOverflow em Português deveria se basear?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1229/74)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não existe configuração de zona horária no site, e todos os horários são exibidos em UTC (que é o horário global padrão, equivalente ao de Greenwich/GMT). Isso  vale para todos os sites da rede.

Sempre que você vir uma data e horário no site, a referência é o UTC. Então para calcular qual seria o horário equivalente no Brasil, você precisa subtrair 3 horas (ou 2, se estiver dentro do Horário Brasileiro de Verão). Mas geralmente é mais fácil simplesmente "pensar em UTC" enquanto usa o site (e por isso mesmo existe aquela indicação da hora atual em UTC no dropdown de realizações).

Comment: E Feliz Natal :)

Comment: Obrigado, feliz natal a todos

Comment: @bfavaretto detalhe, UTC so e equivalente a GMT durante o periodo de Inverno. GMT observa Daylight Saving Time. Nessa altura, UTC = GMT - 1.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento, @Omni. Nada como um londrino pra saber essas coisas :)